# Don't Send Email by hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I use code below to send email, but I get this error every time

> Failure sending mail.

My code:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage("donot-reply@mydomain.ir", "reception@yahoo.com", "test", "msg");
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient("mail.mydomain.ir",110);
emailClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("donot-reply@mydomain.ir", "donot-replyA!1");
emailClient.EnableSsl = true;
emailClient.Send(message);
```

I can send email by this email address in thunder birds, but I do not know why I can't send the email in .NET

Comment: did you look at the stack trace? There must be more detail to the exception you are getting

Comment: SMTP servers usually respond with more than just "Failure sending mail".  What are the details from the server's response?  Where *specifically* does this fail?  It's entirely possible that there's nothing wrong with the code at all and the SMTP server is simply refusing to deliver the message.

Comment: @David how can i get server response?

Comment: @job1393: If `.Send()` is throwing an exception then there will likely be details in that exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a quick glance, your using an invalid *Simple Mail Transfer Protocol* port, try the following:

- Port: **25**
- Port: **587**

Without a Stack Trace or more information on your error we won't be much use.

Comment: I change port to 587 and it'e ok . but when i run program and debug it and press **f11** it's ok and send mail but when remove break point and run it don't send.why ?